# Trigger on Manage Currency

Tags: trigger, custom-object, multi-currency, advanced

I am having a requirement in which if a user create a record of manage currency(Setup > Company Profile > Manage Currencies) after creation of the record a custom object record should also be created.
Is it possible to write a trigger on manage currency?

Comment: What do you mean by "create a record of manage currency"? I assume the org has Multiple Currencies enabled. Do you mean, when a currency is added to the list of Active Currencies? ... in any case, I don't think you're going to be able to trigger on them, since currencies are metadata.

Comment: Thanks  Carolyn Grabill for your reply. Is there any way to create a record in custom object as a currency is added to the "Manage Currency" instantly.Right now i am using the batch apex for this requirement.